# automated way to create BIM objects (.rvt .aat format)

Tags: revit, ifc, archicad

Is there an automated way to create BIM objects in revit(.rvt) or archicad(.aat) format from product data(xml)?
What is needed to create such an object?

Answer (score 0):

The Revit API requires a valid running Revit end user session. Technically, you can tweak it to drive it from outside, but that is not what it is designed for. Here is more on that topic, and several working examples:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.28

My samples connecting desktop and cloud do something similar as well:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/10/connecting-desktop-and-cloud-at-rtc-material.html

We are working on implementing functionality to create and modify Revit RVT models directly in the cloud, aka Revit I/O, and are very interested in hearing your requirements in that area:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.28b